# Maps and mobile zoom issue

Tags: mobile, accessibility, w3c, zooming, pinchzoom

An issue I have with maps on mobile devices is that sometimes when trying to zoom in the map I zoom in the viewport instead - so that the map and text become larger. This happens mostly with inadvertent double taps when out and about, but sometimes happens with pinch zoom. It means that my controls (at the bottom of the viewport) disappear. It can then be rather tricky to (pinch) zoom out the viewport to get the full view of my app back.

The problem is easily fixed by inserting user-scalable=no in the meta, thus:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But apparently this is a no-no: http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-accessibility-mapping/#zoom-magnification section 1.4.4

My app is subscription based, and I think the issue of inadvertent viewport zooming is worse than not allowing subscribers to zoom the viewport. So I've left the "user-scalable=no" for now, but am curious to know if there's a way users can say increase zoom on forms but not on maps.

Thanks in advance
Mini

Answer (score 0):

Simple: don't mix your map with other content. Make your map the full screen when you want to zoom the map and then turn off the map zoom when the map is not the whole screen.

There is no other way, because when you zoom your map, you need to call preventDefault, which also disables the standard pinch to zoom.

Comment: Hm, my map view has a row of buttons (e.g +, -, position) at the bottom, so I don't want it to be the full screen. I'm using OpenLayers 2, so I'm letting that handle the events ...

Answer (score 0):

Note that the documentation says that it **should** not, that it **must**:

> Restrictive values for user-scalable and maximum-scale attributes of this meta element **should** be avoided.

When we have a web application, **we do want the control to stay at the bottom** when we pinch zoom the viewport, like a standard web browser always have its menu bar visible when we zoom inside the content. **Web app controls are not part of the content**.

Then, you **can** have a restriction on the viewport size for the full window, **as long** as your main content (here the map) is scalable.

This will require that your content will always be in an iframe which has no restriction on its scalability.

**Your can (and should?) perfectly consider using a font for your controls which is at less 200% of the initial content text size in order to fulfill WCAG recommendations (or must? Definitely).**